# Snorkel: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: python

When I try to execute: `from snorkel.learning import GenerativeModel`
I got an error saying: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

I am using Ubuntu 16.0

Comment: Your question is remotely about `python`, but it is not about `import`, `installation`, `nlp` and `system`. Use only the relevant tags.

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a bug in `snorkel`, whatever that is.